# Can I replace a certain character in a string with another string?

Tags: java, string, replace

I'm trying to make a hangman game.  s is the string that contains the user's guess, and hiddenWord is a string of all question marks until the user guesses one of the letters correctly.  How could I replace the question marks with the s string?

```
public void correctGuess()
{
    hiddenWord.replace ("?", s);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "That was correct! Guess again.");
}
```

Comment: You can't replace a character in a String.  You can, however, construct a new String which contains the contents of a prior String, only with some characters replaced.  You do that with `replace`.

Answer (score 2):

The [`replace` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) doesn't change the original `String`, which is immutable.  It returns the modified `String`.  Try

```
hiddenWord = hiddenWord.replace("?", s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply replace characters in strings in java, as strings are immutable. What you can do is create a new string the way rgettman suggested.

But would it not replace all the question marks in the hiddenWord with the s instead of replacing them only at the index(s) where the letter, which the user correctly guessed, is found in the hiddenWord?